# UMVUE and Cramér-Rao lower bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, statistical-inference, density-function

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $X_1 , \dots , X_n \sim$ Bernoulli$(\theta)$, iid. Find $T_n$, the UMVUE of $\theta(1-\theta)$, and show that Var($T_n$) does not attain the Cramér-Rao lower bound.

My attempt to solve the problem was first find the sufficient statistic $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \sim$ Binomial$(n,p)$.

Then, I found the UMVUE to be $T_n = \dfrac{n}{n-1}\bar{X}(1-\bar{X})$, where $\bar{X} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{n}$.

The Cramér-Rao lower bound is: $\dfrac{(1-2\theta)^2}{n\left[\theta(1-\theta) \right]^{-1}}$

I got stuck on finding the Variance of $T_n$, since:

$Var(T_n) = \left(\dfrac{n}{n-1}\right)^2 Var(\bar{X}(1-\bar{X})) = \left(\dfrac{n}{n-1}\right)^2 \left[\dfrac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n} + \dfrac{Var((\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2)}{n^2}\right]$

Is there a simpler way to find $Var((\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2)$ than taking the 4th derivative of m.g.f. to get $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^4$?

> Obs: this was a test question with limited time to solve.

Comment: I honestly would just use the MGF. Recall that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \sim \text{Binomial}(n, p)$ and just take the second and fourth derivatives of the MGF. You don't have to worry about every term, because you're just evaluating the MGF derivatives at $t = 0$.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to show that the variance is greater than the lower bound without finding it explicity. Finding the 4th moment trough mgf consumed a valuable time on this test....

Comment: i asked this same question on CV. guess theres not a faster way.. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328296/how-to-compute-variance-of-squared-binomial-rv